# Beginner questions about vim

Tags: c++, windows, vim

Question #1:
if I have a C++ code like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namesapce std;

int main() {
  int a;
  cin >> a;
  cout << a << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this is called (debugging, compiling, or building), but I just want to run this program inside gvim so I can give it the input and see the output, and see errors such as "missing ';' " or "missing '}' " (like what happens when I click F9 in "Code::Blocks").
exe file, and other things are not important for me.

Question #2:
if I have a C++ code that I write every time like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
```

How can I make vim insert this code every time I open a .cpp file with vim ?

I have Windows 7 32-bit and my .vimrc file is the default one that comes when I install vim.
Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: `vim` has a `:make` command, but you'll first have to configure it with your compiler details.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions on the same time, that's not how Stack Overflow Works. Use the "Edit" link to change this question to only contain the first one. Then post your second question separately. That will also make the heading and tagging less confusing, when you're only asking one thing in each question.

Comment: Uh, that code you want in every opened file is definitely *not a good practice*.

Comment: using namespace std; is okay to start, but isn't a good practice, as it can cause lots of problems to occur in your code that are hard to debug.  As you get deeper into C++, you'll probably want to stop putting that at the top of your files.  But at the start its okay.

Comment: @Griwes the question was with every .cpp file not every file

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito, still holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably this is what you are looking for

[Vi and Vim Autocommand: 3 Steps to Add Custom Header To Your File Automatically](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/)

Answer (score 2):

Q1:  You'll need to compile your C++ code first to "see errors such as "missing ';' " or "missing '}'".  Then you can run your compiled EXE to determine if your input and output values work.  In Visual Studio, hitting the play button (Debug) will do both.

Q2:  vim has a set of events that occur that allow you to perform certain actions, like append text to a new file with an extension of .cpp.  You would add some code to your .vimrc file to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it on opening up use autocmd. You can do it like [lipun4u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727329/beginner-questions-about-vim/11727479#11727479) said:

1. [Vim autocommand auto add headers at start of file](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/vi-and-vim-autocommand-3-steps-to-add-custom-header-to-your-file/)

---

Well I suggest getting this plugin: [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)

> snipMate.vim aims to be an unobtrusive, concise vim script that implements some of TextMate's snippets features in Vim. A snippet is a piece of often-typed text that you can insert into your document using a trigger word followed by a tab.

It has several features:

1. More than 1 language supported
2. Lots of premade snippets
3. **Ability to make your own snippets**

So this way you can have different headers for different programs, and just assign them to a hot key.